# How many hidden layers are there?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    
model.add(Flatten())  
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

As far as I understand, `model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))` is the input layer here and `model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))` is the output layer.

There are a total `13` other layers between the input and output layers. So are there 13 hidden layers in the model? Or less? What are the names of the layers that should be counted as hidden layers?

I am confused about whether `Activation` or `MaxPooling2D` or `Dropout` should be counted as a single hidden layer or not.

Comment: it depends a lot on the definition of layer you use, for example if you want to count as layers only those operation with actual trainable parameters you would have only 5 layers ( and you put convolution activation function and pooling together), i would probably count 12 layers ( because dropout is not really a layer, only an inibitor)

Comment: Are there a lot of definitions of layers? Is relu activation function a layer? @BestDogeStackoverflow

Comment: yes, online gets usually defined as a layer, i had a hard time finding an official definition of what excatly is a layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activation functions are not the hidden layers.
Layers will be - Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dense

You can use below code to get the model architecture details.

model.summary()

Comment: So how many hidden layers are there in the model mentioned in the question?